# How to set Nginx reverse proxy for local Docker Django

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

I'm developing a docker project with `nginx` and `django` services. I've `django.conf.template` parameterised to pass environment variables dynamically depends on environment.

django.conf:

```
upstream django_app {
  server  ${DJANGO_PRIVATE_IP}:${DJANGO_PORT};
}

server {

  listen  80;
  listen  443 ssl;
  listen  [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name   ${NGINX_SERVER_NAME};

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/elitecars_cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/elitecars_privkey.pem;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.django.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.django.error.log;

  location / {

    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    Host               $host;

    proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_pass  http://django_app;
  }
}
```

The template works well because i can see the env vars values with `more /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-available/django.conf` command

```
upstream django_app {
  server  django:8000;
}

server {

  listen  80;
  listen  443 ssl;
  listen  [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name   0.0.0.0 127.0.0.1 localhost;
  ...
```

But when I tried to access through the browser but doesn't work.

Any idea? Anybody could help me please?

Comment: I think we'll need more detail. What exactly is the response you get from the browser? What address are you accessing exactly? Https? Using an IP or a name?  Also, can you access other URLs on your nginx container? You could try to isolate the problem and establish whether: A) your browser cant talk to the nginx or B) your nginx cant talk to the django..  Try to break it up a bit.  Maybe run curl locally in the nginx container and see whether the nginx process is happy and whether it can find the upstream django.  You've got several layers there, try to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On local and Mac I need to add host.docker.internal IP to /etc/hosts for nginx config file like this:

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
172.17.0.1       localhost
...
```

And solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The IP specified in upstream section is incorrect. The correct syntax is:

```
upstream django_app {
  server  0.0.0.0:8000;
}
```

Comment: I need Docker service host name to be reachable from nginx docker container